# IntelliJ Compiles Modules Perfectly But Maven Compile Task Fails

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea, java-8, maven-plugin

I have a Maven project with 17 modules that I'm editing using IntelliJ 2020.2.  It uses the bundled Maven version 3.6.3.

If I ask IntelliJ to run Junit tests in each module they compile and pass without a problem.

But when I run the compile, install, or deploy Maven lifecycle task in the root pom the modules fail to compile:

```
Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.8.1:testCompile (default-testCompile) on project qq-dtc-properties: Fatal error compiling
```

If I add debug flags and re-run the Maven task I don't see any errors or new information.

Why would IntelliJ successfully build and run test cases but Maven fail?

Here's the really weird part.

If I run the root compile task it fails once, twice, but succeeds on the third try.  I had to repeat that for each module.  It's like a partridge in a pear tree: I build that first module 3*17 = 51 times.

I'm mystified about Maven't behavior.  Has anyone else seen something like this?

Comment: To make sure I get what you're saying...Maven execution is deterministic, but fails 2 out of each 3 times you run it?  When it does fail, the only information you get is the error message you provide? I've done a lot of things with Maven, and both of these behaviors surprise me. - If that's all we have to go on, then the best chance that you get help is if this matches behavior someone else has seen.  I have no idea what to do with this except to ask if there is ANY additional information?

Comment: I've done a lot of things with Maven, and those behaviors astound me.  No code changes, but a module will fail to compile twice and then succeed.  Same code.

Comment: And that's really all the accompanying information you get in the Maven output?

Comment: I would be happy to post more if it was pertinent.  I'm not holding out on anybody who can help me.

Comment: So I guess that's a "Yes", which is all I was looking for both times I asked.  Excuse me for assuming that you'd assume I was asking only for pertinent information.

Comment: "Excuse me" - I'd expect somebody who claims such long experience to have a thicker skin.  You're reading something that isn't there.  I gave the information that I see.  It's not about you.

Comment: Could you be precise with the command that fails and complete the errors logged by Maven? Also, just as you mention, are the errors suppressed with the debug flag enabled? Since you are pretty aware of the SO construct, I may ask for a minimal reproducible code as well (creating that helps me solve the problem on my own quite often.)

Comment: Do you get the same error if you run Maven command from command line outside IDE?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found my answer.

When I used the `maven.compiler.source` and `maven.compiler.target` default variable names I had a problem.

All was well after replacing them with custom variable names `common-modules.compiler.source` and `common-modules.compiler.target`, set in `<properties>` in the bill of materials `pom`:

```
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>${maven-compiler-plugin.version}</version>
            <configuration>
                <parameters>true</parameters>
                <source>${common-modules.compiler.source}</source>
                <target>${common-modules.compiler.target}</target>
                <release>${common-modules.compiler.release}</release>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
```